# Featured Document as promoted link

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Forgive me if this has already been asked and answered -

I have a list of PDF docs, I would like to have a promoted link on another page that chooses one of the PDFs as a promoted link and then cycles through the list of PDFs each week, choosing either one at random, or sequentially... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For quick solution I would add HTML Forms web part, and add there bunch of JavaScript code, that fetches PDF list items, and cycles them using JavaScript.

You can get list items using JavaScript via ListData.svc (I think _api wasn't yet available in SP Foundation) `http://myserver/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ListName`, e.g., if using jQuery

```
var ajaxCall = $.getJSON("http://myserver/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ListName");

ajaxCall.success(function (jsonData) { // do something with jsonData.d.results });
ajaxCall.error(function () { //error occurred });
```

And finally add a fancy marquee or some other type of looping UI goodness, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547797/very-simple-very-smooth-javascript-marquee